# Calculate a value from drop down list that uses sqldatasource as data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

So basically i want to do calculation based on selected index in Dropdown list that uses sqldatasource as it sources and having trouble to view it on another page.I'm using session in the process.

Here's the coding for the Dropdown list's that is using sqldatasource :-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlMRoom" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Room" DataValueField="Price" Height="16px" Width="84px" Visible="False">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FlightConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Room], [Price] FROM [Meneur Hotel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlGRoom" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Room" DataValueField="column1" Height="16px" Width="84px" Visible="False">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FlightConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Room], [Price (RM)] AS column1 FROM [Gardenia Hotel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlARoom" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="Room" DataValueField="column1" Height="16px" Width="84px" Visible="False">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FlightConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Room], [Price (RM)] AS column1 FROM [Al-Rashid Hotel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlPRoom" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="Room" DataValueField="column1" Height="16px" Width="84px" Visible="False">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FlightConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Room], [Price (RM)] AS column1 FROM [Petra Sella Hotel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlTORoom" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="Room" DataValueField="column1" Height="16px" Width="84px" Visible="False">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FlightConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Room], [Price (RM)] AS column1 FROM [The Olive Branch Hotel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here's one of example of my calculation : -

```
int calculation()
{   
    int price=0;

    if(DdlMRoom.SelectedIndex==1)
    {
        int price;
        price = Convert.ToInt16(DdlMRoom.SelectedValue) * Convert.ToInt16(TxtPax.Text);
    }

    return price;

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    calculation().ToString();
    Session["Price"] = price;

    Response.Redirect("View.aspx);
}
```

Here's the coding on View.aspx & .cs : -

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblPrice.Text = Session["Price"].ToString();  
}
```

i hope someone can answer this, i'm doing this for assignment and is due tomorrow. Will be terrific if any of you guys help me!!

Comment: you are not storing the result of `calculation().ToString()`. I dont see how this line `Session["Price"] = price;` would work when there is no variable named price within that function's scope

Comment: @Bowofola so does that mean i have to assign another variable in protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) then? e.g prices = calculate().ToString(); Session["Price"]=prices; does this means its possible to calculate a value from sqldatasource? i googled and it said using this dataview thing and i just dont get it.

Comment: You definitely have to do that cause what you have currently shouldn't even build to me. What happened when you tried to run it?

Comment: also you cant declare `int price` twice in `calculation()`

Comment: @Bowofola thank you so much for point out that!! now my system works fine!! god bless you

Comment: nice! mark the answer correct pls

Comment: done :) @Bowofola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
int calculation()
{   
    int price=0;

    if(DdlMRoom.SelectedIndex==1)
    {
        price = Convert.ToInt16(DdlMRoom.SelectedValue) * Convert.ToInt16(TxtPax.Text);
    }

    return price;

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    string price = calculation().ToString();
    Session["Price"] = price;

    Response.Redirect("View.aspx");
}
```